# How to Update the DataFrame after Inner joining and then left outer joining

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to  Update the DataFrame after Inner joining and then left outer joining
mysql query which needs to be converted

```
   UPDATE SUD a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (RS_DF b 
                    INNER JOIN prlesp 
                    ON b.cid = p.cid 
                    and p.PS = b.PS ) 
ON a.cid = p.cid  
AND a.id = b.aid 

val updated_Df = RS_DF.join(prles_DF, prles(cid) <=>  RS_DF(aid) &&  prles(cid) <=>  RS_DF(aid),"INNER").select(*).join(.....)
```

I cant understand how to get all the values from the join and again Left outer join on SUD_DF and Update the values

Comment: any one can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Spark DataFrames are immutable structures. you cannot update a DataFrame. Instead, you must transform a dataframe into a new DataFrame. You can then write that new dataframe out to disk or some other datastore.